# Placing a TextBox on a Canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to spread 18 Textboxes evenly on a Canvas. However, the `Left` Property of the `TextBox` is not set (they all appear on the leftside of the canvas). Why is this code not working?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Months}"> <!-- This is a collection of 18 DateTime values -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=coPlanung}" Background="Aqua" Height="30" Margin="0"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:MMM-yyyy}, Mode=OneWay}" >
                            <Canvas.Left>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource d2x}"> <!-- This is a convert calculating the left value for each Date Item -->
                                    <Binding Path="Date" Mode="OneWay" />
                                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="coPlanung" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Canvas.Left>
                        </TextBox>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>                        
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TextBlock is no direct child of the Canvas in the ItemsPanelTemplate, hence setting `Canvas.Left` has no effect.

You would have to declare an `ItemContainerStyle` with a Setter that binds the `Canvas.Left` property of the item container (i.e. a ContentPresenter, which is created for each item and added as child of the ItemsPanel):

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas .../>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        ...
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Works fine.Thank you very much!